# TypeError: Font.isLoaded is not a function, (in 'Font.isLoaded(fontName)', 'Font.isLoaded' is undefined) in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, ionicons, react-native-vector-icons

I'm building a React Native app using Expo 31.0.4 and Expo Vector icons.
When I'm using Ionicons to build the TabBar, an error occurs.

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const Main = TabNavigator({
    Settings: {
        screen: ProfileStack,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (<Ionicons name="ios-cog" size={25} color={tintColor}/>)
        })
    },
    Deals: {
        screen: DealStack,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (<Ionicons name="ios-list-box" size={25} color={tintColor}/>),
        })
    },
    Checkin: {
        screen: BarcodeScannerScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (<Ionicons name="ios-camera" size={27} color={tintColor}/>)
        })
    },
```

[image: Screenshot]

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like a new issue with Expo 31.0.0;
in my case I solve this as below ;
`npm install`
`expo start -c`

once It works and expo app open as usually you can continue with 
`yarn start` or `npm start`

BTW I use expo 32.0.1 right now.

here is a detailed explanation and different solutions you can check It out;
https://forums.expo.io/t/solved-font-isloaded-is-not-a-function-expo-vector-icons/17787